# Java - Learning Order

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have been self training in java for quite few months and worked on some projects on core java too. I want to increase my knowledge in J2EE and frameworks. Here is the action/study list I have, please suggest me the order in which the study should go(interms of better understanding):

1) EJB
  2) Struts
  3) Spring 
  4) Hibernate
  5) JSP

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should learn Servlets and Jsps and
then Struts (Enchantment of JSP and Servlet Technology) --For Front End Dev
then Hibernate (For Back End Data Base Functionality Enchantment of JDBC)
then Spring Frame Work (By which u can do all three layers Development)
then EJB3 ..

Answer (score 1):

You should learn jsp then you can go any framework like struts,spring or component based framework like JSF and then you can go for EJB

Answer (score 1):

I will offer the following learning order

1. `Java` core,
2. `Servlet`/`JSP`
3. `JDBC`
4. One or more web frameworks: `Struts` (`Struts 2`) or `Spring MVC` or `JSF`
5. `Hibernate` (`JPA2`)
6. `Spring` or `EJB3`

In 6-th point the Spring and EJB3 are different approaches. Learning one of them is usually enough to find a good job (of course you can learn both, but it needs a lot of time).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Hibernate tries to map between Java objects and data in SQL database, which makes it not particularly applicable in cases where you use No-SQL databases (such as, for example, the App Engine Datastore). JSP is actually fairly old-school and not recommended; Java Server Faces (JSF) or alternative templating engines combined with writing custom servlets is more common in newer applications written from scratch than using JSP, as I understand it.

I would start with deciding what platform you expect to be running on (Google App Engine, Amazon Web Services, some other Cloud Platform?), and then use that to drive your learning, since different platforms may have a different set of available and/or recommended APIs to use for writing Java-based servers.

Anyway, here is what I would recommend as far as order is concerned:

1. All the basics of Java.
2. Writing HttpServlet implementations (no JSP or JSF).
3. Writing HttpServlet implementations with JSF.
4. Using Spring or Guice for dependency injection.
5. Using the Java Persistence API (JPA)
6. Everything else.